# Capture a string of digits from within two strings

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to capture a string of digits from within a string of data.  The digits I'm trying to capture starts with 109 and is followed by a space, 2 digits, a comma, and a space.

I'm trying to capture `44444444` in the 1st line; `44455555` in the 2nd line; and `44466666` in the 3rd line.

Line 1:  109STAYPAY (HK) LTD               ,OCMT,HKD123,55,                                                             44444444 99,99 ,RFB,WPAANNRFFB
Line 2:  109FLAYPAY (HK) LTD               ,OCMT,HKD456,79,                                                             44455555 88,88 ,RFB,WPAANNRFEF
Line 3:  109HOLLPAY PTE LTD                 44466666 77,77 ,RFB,WPAANNREXU

[image]

I have tried the following expression:

```
(?<=108)(.*)(?= [0-9][0-9],[0-9][0-9] ,)
```

but it is not providing me with the information I'm looking for.

Comment: `109 and is followed by a space` none of your examples have a space after `109`. Also not sure why you have `108` in regex if looking for `109`, is this your actual example and code?

Comment: I suspect you want `109.*? \K\d+(?= \d{2},\d{2} ,)`

Comment: My apologies.  This should have been 109.  Is there a way that I can flex this when the line starts with 108 or 109?

Comment: Why are you trying to match _just_ the `4444444` for example ? Because unless you use certain RX engines, you're going to have to settle for getting that number in a capture group. Meaning a lot will be matched. Sorry but there is no way to avoid this. In other words, it does no good using the look ahead assertion if you have to match a bunch of pre-text as well as the 4444444444.

Comment: As for the 108/109, thats done like so  `10[89]` Also, engines that would support a pre-text, variable length look behind assertions - filter are JS, C# (Dot Net) and Pcre or Pert that support `\K`.

Comment: `10[98].*? \K\d+(?= \d{2},\d{2} ,)`. Without any more details, and judging by the screenshot, you are using it in Notepad++, and it supports `\K` but not a variable width lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the surrounding text to identify the value.

```
\d{8}(?= \d\d)
```

I guess you can even *capture* and evaluate the subsequent digits.

```
\d{8}(?= ((\d)\2),\1)
```

Alternately, use a *capture pattern*.

```
109.+?(\d{8})
```